# SQL - if exists return always 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT usernev AS juzernev, SUM(mbsent) AS summ FROM data WHERE datum > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND usernev='csib')'";
```

I have this query on this table(data) - the first col. is the usernev:

```
| sajtos    |   1323 |   411 | 193.225.249.2  | 10.8.0.10 |  3661 | 2015-03-19 17:25:37 | 87 |
| csib      |    318 |    26 | 5.187.169.135  | 10.8.0.6  | 10849 | 2015-03-19 19:11:37 | 88 |
| csib      |      5 |     1 | 5.187.169.135  | 10.8.0.6  |  1234 | 2015-03-19 22:50:23 | 89 |
| gyuri     |     26 |    31 | 193.225.249.2  | 10.8.0.14 |  3001 | 2015-03-19 22:56:54 | 90 |
```

So the problem is when i use this query it is returns 1 -> So with this query with username csib there were good results. But when i change the usernev to another (which is not exists) it is also returns 1.
Am i doing something wrong or i cant do it with EXISTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aggregation function with no `group by` always returns one row.  And, a query that has one row satisfies `exists`.

As a general rule, I always use `select 1` with `exists`.  There is no need to select anything more:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM data
               WHERE datum > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND 
                     usernev = 'csib'
              );
```

You can also write this query as:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(1), 0)
FROM data
WHERE datum > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND 
      usernev = 'csib';
```

With an index on `data(usernev, datum)`, the two probably have similar performance.  Otherwise, the first would have better performance.  I just mention this version because it has an aggregation function, making use of the fact that an aggregation query with no `group by` always returns one row.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using aggregate function `sum` and this will always return one row weather or not if there is any data.
You may need to remove the aggregate function inside the `exists`

Here is a demo

```
mysql> select exists (select sum(amount) from paymentlog where idusers = 1 );
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| exists (select sum(amount) from paymentlog where idusers = 1 ) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                              1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select exists (select sum(amount) from paymentlog where idusers = 1111111111 );
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| exists (select sum(amount) from paymentlog where idusers = 1111111111 ) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select exists (select * from paymentlog where idusers = 1111111111 );
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| exists (select * from paymentlog where idusers = 1111111111 ) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             0 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```